# how to add URL link in a SharePoint list?

Tags: windows-server

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template. I am using List Web Part with Data Sheet view. I want to know how to make a column as a URL link (i.e. show text in the cell, and can associate a link with the text in each row for the specific column), i.e. when user clicks the text in the specific column of a specific row, the user will be directed to the link associated the text.

Comment: This is MOSS, not WSS right?

Comment: If he's using the publishing portal, he's using MOSS

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the rendering of Data Sheet View (AFAIK), but you can customize regular web parts. Check this [blog post](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/14/data-view-web-part-the-basics-add-a-hyperlink/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a "Hyperlink or Picture" column to the list you should be able to add it to the data sheet view.

When you've done that, you should be able to edit the contents of a field by going: Right-click, Hyperlink -> Edit Hyperlink.